# Loop through object in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understanding Jquery and I am having problems to append values from a array.

I have created the object below with:

```
var obj = [];
```

I put it trough a loop pushing data:

```
 obj.push({
     name: name,
     address: address,
     comment: comment,
     distance: distance,
     duration: duration,
     lat: lat,
     lng: lat,
     count: count,
     order: order
 });
```

My `console.log(obj)`:

```
0: Object
address: "Test"
comment: "My comment"
count: 1
distance: "3.3 mi"
duration: "13 mins"
lat: "44.971424"
lng: "44.971424"
name: "My House"
order: "3.3"

1 : Object 
2 : Object 
3 : Object 
4 : Object 
5 : Object
```

My question is:

How can I append to a div?

```
$("#div_result").each(obj, function(){
    // ??
    // This is not working for me. 
});
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Using debug with $this inside each and try to get what you need there

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append values from your object to a DIV, you can try the following code.

```
$.each(obj, function( index, value ) { 
    $("#div_result").append(index + ' and ' + value );
});
```

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(obj, function( index, value ) { 
    console.log(value.address);
    console.log(value.comment);
    .... and so on.....
});
```